# Receiving IOError: [Errno 13] running Python on PC without restrictions

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am getting an IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied when I run the following command in Python.  I am running Windows 7.  Is there a portion of this code that can be modified to utilize a different approach, but receive the same result.  I need to move all files in one directory to another directory in Windows.

```
import shutil

# Copy src to dst. (cp src dst)
shutil.copy('C:/AUTOREPORTS/','C:/WINGNUTS/')
```

Comment: What part of "[Errno 13] Permission denied" is unclear?

Comment: I have full permissions to all files.  Especially to the ones that I create.  Basically, I am just looking to move all files in directory X to directory Y.  I am still new to Python, so I must be doing something stupid here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few issues:

1. `shutil.copy` is for copying *files* not entire directories. You need to use [`shutil.copytree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree)
2. Unless you have manually modified permissions of those two directories, copying from or to any directory at `C:\` requires elevated privileges. Try running the script from an [elevated command prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/735457/elevate-cmd-to-admin-with-command-prompt).